# ZF2 forms - insert and update forms

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This is more of a question of approach/best practice, than a specific technical question, so I come to you for a bit of guidance.

My question surrounds Zend Framework 2 forms, and specifically if I should be implementing a different form for insetting entities and updating entities.

To outline a simplified use case.  Let's say I have a product table in my database.  Each product has an ID (`product_id`) which is the primary key and a name (`name`).  Let's say the products I am storing come from a supplier who provide me with a unique product id which I want to use for my primary key in the database.

Now, let's say I've implemented a `product_fieldset` and a `product_form`, both of which are working nicely.  The form allow me to specify the product ID and name and store it in the database.  However, when a user uses the form to update a product name, rather than insert a new product, I don't want them to be able to edit the product ID as this is my database primary key.

I can currently only see how I could present the form in an update scenario with one less field (the product ID) by implementing 2 forms and 2 fieldsets.

How would you approach this?  When using the service manager/form manager to pull back my forms, I can't quite get my head around how/where or even if I should implement logic within the form to deal with such situations.

:wq

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

> Let's say the products I am storing come from a supplier who provide me with a unique product id which I want to use for my primary key in the database.

That is a SKU number. Keep your primary keys for the database's management. If there is an external identifier, store that separately.

Then I would always reuse the form for both insert and update. This becomes quite trivial when your SKU is a different property than your primary key. An example in code, see this model:

```
<?php
class Product
{
  protected $id;
  protected $sku;
  protected $name;

  // getters & setters here
}

class Form extends \Zend\Form\Form
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->add(array(
      'name' => 'sku',
    ));

    $this->add(array(
      'name' => 'name',
    ));
  }
}

class Controller extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController
{
  public function createAction()
  {
    $form    = new Form;
    $product = new Product;
    $form->bind($product);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
      $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
      $form->setData($data);

      if ($form->isValid()) {
        // get service to update
        $service->create($product);

        // redirect to view
      }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
      'form' => $form,
    ));
  }

  public function updateAction()
  {
    $form    = new Form;
    // Load product based on the ID
    $form->bind($product);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
      $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
      $form->setData($data);

      if ($form->isValid()) {
        // get service to update
        $service->update($product);

        // redirect to view
      }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
      'form'    => $form,
      'product' => $product,
    ));
  }
}
```

This means the model keeps always an ID "for itself" and the SKU can be updated anytime. The update uses the id from the request (e.g. you have an url `admin/product/edit/123`) and the SKU number is differently and can be updated.

By this means, the form can be kept the same for both the update and the create methods. I usually use a service layer to persist the object, you should do it the way you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Jurian, and yes I agree, primary key should be kept for the database management.  The only reason I was trying to use the SKU in this case is because my models (and there are thousands of them) are updated regularly from an XML feed.  By having the SKU as a primary key, I could use MySql's 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' feature to very quickly update the database from a feed of thousands of items where the SKU is the unique identifier.  Without this, for every item I would first have to search the database to see if it exists and make a decision to update according to the result.

Comment: You can use an `INSERT IGNORE` query or use an `INSERT [...] WHERE NOT EXISTS` otherwise. For the first one (all errors in the insert will be skipped, mind that!) you just have a unique constraint on the SKU and then insert all the data from your feed. Though, that is a different topic and not really related to above ZF2 problem. Search SO about this topic, there are plenty questions about it :)